# Скидка на товар Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите как реализовать следующие, чтобы зарегистрированный пользователь, который закажет товар в текущем месяце получал скидку 5% на все последующие заказы в течении всего года

Comment: Создайте скидку, создайте группу пользователей которые могут пользоваться этой скидкой, поместите нужного пользователя в эту группу. Надейтесь что сработает (это же Битрикс)

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать новую группу пользователей
2. Дать скидку 5% на все товары и ограничить скидку по времени
3. Повесить обработчик события получения оплаты в котором проверять оплачен ли заказ полностью и дату оформления заказа и если всё подходит добавлять его в созданную группу на которую действует скидка.

---

Второй вариант - выдавать купоны на скидку

Answer (score 0):

В версии 17.0 модуля "интернет магазин" анонсирован новый тип условия применимости скидки "предыдущий заказ". Весьма вероятно, что именно он вам поможет.  https://broadcast.comdi.com/rttu55xilup0paoix9mb (с 15 минуты начинается рассказ про новые скидки). К сожалению документации нету, только это видео.

Если же требуется контролировать доступность скидки в течении года, то стоит добавлять пользователя в группу, к которой привязана скидка, но с добавлением срока окончания участия в группе.